# i cannot use $set operator and $inc operator together only one is working in my case

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
const User = require('./model.js)

    const result = await User.updateMany({_id:{$in:team}},{ $set: { current_level_status : 'incomplete' , user_helper_status : false,user_admin_status : false }},{$inc:{level_number:1}});
console.log(result)
```

i am using mongoose set operator and increment operator together

mongoose 'updateMany' is not working with this operators
team field contains array of object ids

Answer (score 3):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany

1. filter «Object»
2. doc «Object»
3. [options] «Object» optional see Query.prototype.setOptions()

---

The problem is you're passing `$inc` in the 3rd parameter instead of joining it with same object inside 2nd parameter.

---

Change

```
const result = await User.updateMany(
 {_id:{$in:team}}, // Parameter 1
 {$set: { current_level_status : 'incomplete' , user_helper_status : false,user_admin_status : false }}, // Parameter 2
 {$inc:{level_number:1}} // Parameter 3
);
```

To

```
const result = await User.updateMany(
 {_id:{$in:team}}, // Parameter 1
 { // Parameter 2
    $set: { current_level_status : 'incomplete' , user_helper_status : false,user_admin_status : false }
    $inc: {level_number:1}
 }
);
```

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/7zHcJy_sh-H

Comment: i found this little more easy and short                                                                                                             `await User.updateMany(
        {_id:{$in:team}},
        { $set: { current_level_status : 'incomplete' , user_helper_status : false,user_admin_status : false }, $inc: { level_number:1 } },

     )`

Comment: @JewelKWilson What the difference here it's exactly the same what my answer is?

Answer (score 0):

`$inc` should be in second parameter of the `update()` function, but outside of the `$set`:

```js
User.updateMany({ _id: { $in: team } }, { 
  $set: { 
    current_level_status: 'incomplete',
    user_helper_status: false,
    user_admin_status : false 
  },
  $inc: { level_number: 1 }
});
```